# Conectar FTP a mi API de nodejs express para subir fotos de perfil

Tags: nodejs, express

necesito subir info de usuarios, pero la subida de fotos de perfil me pidieron que lo haga mediante ftp, osea que al momento de crear el usuario, la foto se guarde en un servidor ftp.

ya tengo mi servidor ftp y mi cliente ftp. Pero no se como hacer la implementación en Express para poder guardar estas fotos.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, revisa el contenido de los siguientes enlaces: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour (aquí obtienes tu primera medalla y al mismo tiempo aprendes cómo funciona la temática del sitio, no es un foro común y silvestre) + recomendaciones de cómo generar preguntas con altas chances de obtener respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.